# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString question

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, string, file

I am trying to use this line of code

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test();"];
```

but it is not working. I have multiple javascript files and I do not know how to tell the program which one I am trying to use. The files are being loaded from a local html file. If anyone  knows how I would really appreciate it or if someone knows another way  of use objective c to call javascript.

Thanks
Clinton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely you are trying to run this before the HTML is loaded. `WebView` loads asynchronously, even if the files are local. You need to implement `WebFrameLoadDelegate` and wait from `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` before attempting to engage the embedded JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test();"];
```

is correct. The only thing I can think of as cause of your problem is that for some reason the javascript file containing the `test` function is not being loaded.

Try this:

```
NSString* result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title;"];
```

and see whether you get a value in `result`.

EDIT:

If you are loading a local HTML file which contains references to local javascript files, then the most likely cause for your kind of wrong behavior, is not specifying the `baseURL` when initializing the `UIWebView`, e.g.:

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

This should allow you to correctly load javascript files available in your resources folder:

```
NSString* basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
[_label loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath]];
```

If you give more details about how your HTML/javascript files are organized, I can help you further with this (if my hypothesis is correct).

EDIT 2:

(In the following, I assume that your are on MacOS, but I realize that this has not been stated anywhere here; if it where iOS, similar reasoning would apply, but details would be different)

First off, does your delegate method `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` get called? Or is `–webView:didFailLoadWithError:forFrame:` called?

As stated in another answer, you can only execute javascript *after* the webView has been loaded.

On the other hand, I am pretty sure that you are not passing correctly the `baseURL`

```
 NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"allFiles"]; 
 htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath]; 
 [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlPath]];
```

in this snippet, `baseURL` is your `<prefix>/allFiles/index.html` file; you should simply pass `<prefix>/allFiles` for `baseURL`, and if the rest is ok (meaning, the `didFinishLoad` thing, and the html file referring the scripts with a relative path to the script directory) it should work then.

Now, I cannot suggest a way to find out properly the path to the directory "allFiles" (pretty late here), but just to make a test you could trim your current `htmlPath` to remove from it the "index.html" substring...

Comment: the result is blank. I used your line of code plus 'NSLog(@"result = %@", result);'

Comment: how are you initializing your UIWebView?

Comment: I load my local html like `NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"allFiles"];
  htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
  [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlPath]];` And the html file is in a folder called allFiles in the project folder and the javascript files are in a folder called script in the allFiles folder.

Comment: Nope still nothing. I am not writing the file to the main bundle. I am writing it to `/var/mobile/Applications/0122EB17-C83D-4EED-948D-75A6813390EE/appName.app/allFiles/index.html`